# Django: How to put each graphs on a page without saving it

Tags: django, matplotlib, graph, save, bytesio

I’m struggling to put several graphs created with Matplotlib on a page with saving it on memory. While single graph got success, one more graphs has failed. When I tried to embed two matplotlib graphs (graph1 and graph2) in a webpage, for instance, it were displayed one combined graph. In addition that, the designated color also didn’t work. Why? What I want to know is how to display each graph without integration.

The following are my code
Views.py
Matplotlib graph are converted to binary data and saved on memory
Each graph are connected to url parameter

```
def graph():
#create graph and save it on memory
buff=io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buff, format='png')
bute_file=buff.getvalue()
buff.close
return bute_file


def test_graph(request,para):

if para==1: #graph1
    accounts=[6,2,3,6]
    label=['A','B','C','D']
    col=['darkred','red','orange','gold']
    plt.pie(accounts,labels=label,colors=col)
    chart=graph()
    plt.cla
    response=HttpResponse(chart, content_type='image/png')
    return response

elif para==2: #graph2
    accounts=[3,6,9]
    label=['E','F','G']
    col=['blue','cyan','darkblue']
    plt.pie(accounts,labels=label,colors=col)
    chart=graph()
    plt.cla
    response=HttpResponse(chart, content_type='image/png')
    return response

else: #graph3
    accounts=[5,1,2]
    label=['X','Y','Z']
    col=['green','limegreen','yellowgreen']
    plt.pie(accounts,labels=label)
    chart=graph()
    plt.cla
    response=HttpResponse(chart, content_type='image/png')
    return response
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('test_view/',views.test_view, name='test_view'),
path('test/<int:para>',views.test_graph,name='test_graph')
]
```

html

```
 <div>
       <img src="{% url 'mysite:test_graph' 1 %}">
 </div>

 <div>
      <img src="{% url 'mysite:test_graph' 2 %}">
 </div>
```

And here is the displayed page

[image]
Changing para in test_graph() to 3,4 which does not exist on url parameter, the webpage showed exceptional graph(graph3) that seem to work well

Please give me some advices or solution

PS. Does the following message  involve?
 WARNING: NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread! This will throw an exception in the future

---

Edit 
I could solve the WARING message with adding "matplotlib.use('Agg')"

Modifying the test_graph function IAW ger.s.brett advice and eliminating the graph function

```
def test_graph(request,para):
plt.clf()

if para==1: #graph1
    ..........

elif para==2: #graph2
    ..........

else: #graph3
     .........        

plt.pie(accounts,labels=label,colors=col)
buff=io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buff, format='png')
chart=buff.getvalue()
buff.close()

response=HttpResponse(chart, content_type='image/png')
return response
```

---

Edit 2 
Add output graphs, every time accessing to web page
[image]

[image]

[image]

---

I got answer and following are the revised code

view.py

```
class TestView(TemplateView):
template_name='mysite/test.html'

def test_graph(self,accounts,label,col):
    plt.pie(accounts,labels=label,colors=col)
    buff=io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buff, format='png')
    buff.seek(0)
    chart=b64encode(buff.getvalue()).decode('utf-8').replace("","")
    plt.close()
    buff.close()
    return chart

def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context=super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    graph_1=self.test_graph([3,6,9],['E','F','G'],['blue','cyan','darkblue'])
    graph_2=self.test_graph([6,2,3,6],['A','B','C','D'],['darkred','red','orange','gold'])
    context['graph_1']=graph_1
    context['graph_2']=graph_2
    return context
```

test.html

```
<div>
     <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{graph_1}}">
</div>
<div>
     <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{graph_2}}">
</div>
```

So...It was so simple

Comment: Try to clear the plt at the beginning of your  test_graph function: plt.clf().

Comment: Thank ger.s.brett, and I attempt to add plt.clf(). But it didn't solve my trouble at all. What's more, each figure of graph was different , every time repeating the access to test_graph, for example displaying only one graph, two same graph2s or no color graph. So, Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I would be concerned about your handling of the plt object. Why you are not handing this over into the graph function as a function argument?

Comment: I modified the test_graph function and eliminated the graph function, which would cover what you pointed out, perhaps. Even though, this did not still solve my trouble. What do I do.... I'm really at a loss

Comment: What happens now? Twice the same graph?

Comment: Yes, I add the various graphs that were displayed, every time accessing to web page. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use matplotlib with django use sonething like django-matplotlib.

The use of the plt object is only a good idea if you use python interactive.

Comment: Thnak for giving me an addtional advice. I've tried to integrate the django_matplotblib modul into my model, embeding a graph into my web page. But it did not work, while the graph can be displayed on the admin page. This is because the graph was 
not able to be passed from the model (DjangoMatplotlibField). On the other hand, I could find an alternative way which is to switch HttpResponse object as one embeding into html document to a context object. I added the modified code.